# Android Google Maps API, prevent map reloading/redrawing on screen orientation change

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

On my app, when you tilt the device in the mapView, it redraws all the markers. I want to not let this happen.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm facing this problem as well. Maybe it's about managing the mapView in the activity life cycle.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the reloading of the map on screen orientation change I've added in the manifest, in the activity tag this line:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

I don't know if it's the best solution but it works

Answer (score 0):

Try using;

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
```